# Is there a rule for naming columns a certain name?

Tags: sql-server, naming

So we have a SQL Server 2017 instance with the default collation of Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS.

When we create a Temp Table, we see that if a specific name is used, it somehow sees one letter as case sensitive.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #MaterialTest
(
    Product VARCHAR(50),
    Quality VARCHAR (50),
    MaterialOriginGroup VARCHAR (50) 
)

INSERT INTO #MaterialTest VALUES ('Papers', 'Good', 'Test1')
```

If I query this table using:

```
Select Product, Quality, MaterialOriginGroup from #MaterialTest
```

It works fine. If I query it using pretty much anything else it works fine

But if I use a lower case "G" for "Group" in MaterialOriginGroup it fails.

Example:

```
Use TempDB
Select product, quality, materialorigingroup from #MaterialTest
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name
>   'materialorigingroup'.

If I query it with:

```
Use TempDB
Select product, quality, materialoriginGroup from #MaterialTest
```

It works.

Any idea why?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem: [DB<>FIddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=004f2356ff2f13f7b0f74dfa845c96f0). Are you sure it's a `G` character?

Comment: @Larnu You need to either use a SQL Server setup on the `Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS` collation or create a new database with that collation and create the table as non-temporary. I can reproduce the issue

Comment: So collating the character itself doesn't replicate it? That seems like unintended behaviour, @Martin . Literal Strings and Object Names *should* behave the same for comparison.

Comment: This is specifically to do with the letter combination `ng`.  If you create a column `nG`, then using `ng` causes the same failure.  However, if it's `aG`, there is no case sensitivity...

Comment: Here's the issue in action: https://imgur.com/a/uccytru

Comment: @Larnu See the updated fiddle, which seems to reveal that `ng` and `nG` are different: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b586fc9be1670e378a3e0d3701735f31

Comment: Yep, i can replicate with `nG` as well, @Martin . I was explicitly testing `G`, not `nG`. ([DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c71de69d8488a1505e46fd56b91b0ba7))

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. Could this be something to do with the Vietnamese language using nG in specific context?

Answer (score 1):

Building on my own investigations and @Larnu's SQL Fiddle, I've devised a little script to test two-letter combinations:

```
DECLARE @Letter VARCHAR(2);
SET @Letter = 'ch';

DECLARE @LetterA VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @LetterB VARCHAR(1);
SET @LetterA = LEFT(@Letter, 1);
SET @LetterB = RIGHT(@Letter, 1);

SELECT CASE WHEN V.G = UPPER(@Letter) COLLATE Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN V.G = LOWER(@Letter) COLLATE Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN V.G = CONCAT(LOWER(@LetterA), UPPER(@LetterB)) COLLATE Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN V.G = CONCAT(UPPER(@LetterA), LOWER(@LetterB)) COLLATE Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (VALUES(@Letter COLLATE Vietnamese_100_CI_AS_KS)) V(G);
```

This will output 1 or 0 depending upon whether a comparison is valid for the two letter combination.  The comparisons are:

- Upper case letters (i.e. NG)
- Lower case letters (i.e. ng)
- One upper case, one lower case letter (i.e. Ng)
- One lower case, one upper case letter (i.e. nG)

Running this for `ab` produces:

```
1 1 1 1
```

So `ab` does not exhibit this issue.  However, for `ch` you get:

```
1 1 0 1
```

So `ch` *does* exhibit the same issue.

This seems related to declared *consonants* in the Vietnamese alphabet, which include these two-letter consonants:

```
Ch = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Gh = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Gi = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Kh = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Ng = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Nh = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Ph = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Qu = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Th = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
Tr = 1 1 0 1 (has the same issue)
```

Unfortunately, I do not know *why* these are affected by this issue, which is not helpful.  In addition, I don't know *why* it only affects the column name when it is a lowercase followed by an uppercase letter.

Perhaps someone else may see this and know the answer?

The reference for the alphabet is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_alphabet#Consonants).